# How can I make command prompt produce miltiple lines of output simultaniously?

Tags: animation, command-line, echo

I have a batch file that has been aesthetically formatted to display information center console at variable dimensions. In order to achieve this I have used the echo command followed by a period to produce white-space, or just empty space, above and below the content. See the left side of the picture

This works fine for "frames" that switch once per second, but when I remove the the delay it becomes obvious that each 'echo.' is producing one line of white space at a time, creating a rapid scroll, rather than a seamless transition. See the right side of the picture

[[image: here's my picture]]

I've seen a cmd bouncing ball animation on a DIY website, where one of the commenters used a lot of for loops to produce a box with a ball bouncing inside of it. He managed to avoid the scrolling. But that code looked very complicated. I'm not ready to decipher it. But if there were a way to make command prompt produce two ore more lines of white space simultaneously, rather than procedurally, that would be of more use to me. More specifically **the ability to produce, as a single instance of output, a *whole block* of text** would be what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print on the same line, use `echo -ne` with `\r`, which is the return carriage (ie. Print next character at the beginning of the line). Google it for more information.

If you are trying to add intervals between your prints, you can use `sleep`.

Animation is done through careful use of `\r` to start writing the same line(s) over again. This can be done with a single or multiple echos.